# How do I add in a class created in a different android project?

Tags: android, kotlin

Please forgive the vague sounding title

I am trying to get this project to compile in android studio:

https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-create-a-bubble-selection-animation-on-android-627044da4854

https://github.com/igalata/Bubble-Picker

Downloading the github project and compiling it as it is did not work, I am getting [this error](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5617), and redownloading dependencies and syncing as suggested in the error message did not work

UPDATE: I have upgraded android studio, gradle and kotlin plugin to latest version and it's still the same problem.

I can use the library version of this project just fine, using the [steps described in the github page](https://github.com/igalata/Bubble-Picker/blob/develop/README.md). I want to compile the source code of this component together with my project so that I can tweak the bubble animation itself. Since the github project itself does not compile, I created a Hello World project first, then manually copied in the [bubblepicker](https://github.com/igalata/Bubble-Picker/tree/develop/bubblepicker) folder in the Hello World project. Inside the bubblepicker folder, I changed the name of the folder tree [java/com/iglata/bubblepicker](https://github.com/igalata/Bubble-Picker/tree/develop/bubblepicker/src/main) to java/com/test/app/bubblepicker, and changed the package name of the files inside this folder to reflect this.    I then copied the code in [DemoActivity.kt](https://github.com/igalata/Bubble-Picker/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/igalata/bubblepickerdemo/DemoActivity.kt) to my MainActivity.kt and changed the package names and made few minor adjustments to make the compiler errors go away.

I have made some modifications in the gradle files as well so that gradle syncing does not give any errors. However, anything inside bubblepicker does not seem to be detected in the MainActivity.kt, or it's activity layout xml file. For example,

```
import com.test.app.bubblepicker.BubblePickerListener
```

is marked with red colour in android studio and the error is unresolved reference. If I remove all references to bubblepicker and replace the code in MainActivity.kt with the Hello World code, then it compiles and runs fine, so it's as if bubblepicker is not getting picked up by the compiler at all.

What could be the problem here?

Or at the very least, how can I compile the [bubblepicker github project](https://github.com/igalata/Bubble-Picker)? Simply loading the whole project in Android Studio is giving me compiler errors. I am doing this on Android Studio 3.5 on macOS with Kotlin version latest as of September 4.

Comment: did you add that project as dependency to your project?

Comment: @Daniel I don't think so I simply copied the folder from the Mac's windows explorer

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any error while import Github project.
Kindly update your android studio and kotlin Gradle version and check same.

Comment: Android studio is recent updated to 3.5 and gradle is 5.1 I think

Comment: Updating everything to latest version didn't do anything. It still has same problems